# Is there any way to schedule Journey more flexible in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, scheduled-job

As you know, we can set up that the Journey can run every hour automatically. But now we have special requirement.

Do we have a solution or work-around that **Let Journey run from 8:AM to 22:00 PM every Hour everyday** just like based on Cron Expression ?

Answer (score 0):

A very unique scenario. Well here is what I think you can try. 8AM to 10 PM, that's 13 runs.
Step 1. Set the Automation end after 13 runs and set it to run hourly. This will end the automation at 10PM.
Step 2: Create an SSJS activity which will start this automation. Take some ref from here: https://ampscript.com/how-to-run-automations-more-frequently-using-ssjs/
Step 3: Put the above SSJS to an Automation and schedule it to run Daily once at 8AM.

I hope that helps with your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use additional queries and Journey, within the Automation Studio.

1. After every hour, capture the current time and verify if it is within the given time range. Follow the steps mentioned in this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/310616/compare-current-time-hours-with-time-range-in-transaction-sql/311066#311066) (Note- Instead of using File drop, you have to choose 'Schedule' as starting source)
2. After setting up all the steps, you have to add a Query in Step 4 of automation and place the results in your DE.
3. Then use this DE in your Journey. When you schedule your journey, you have to choose the option as 'Automation Studio' and select the automation created earlier.
4. Once you activate the Journey, you should be able to see it in your automation as Step 5
5. Finally, you have to schedule your automation to run every 1 hour and activate it.